# android check row visibility in scrolled tablelayout

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I have a Scrolled TableLayout with hundred row's and I update the content of row's according to timer , I want to to update only the row's are currently appear in the screen and not the  hidden row's in the bottom of ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use

```
int test = tableRow.getVisibity();
```

and use if statements to based on the value obtained?

Comment: I had already used tableRow.getVisibity(); and it always return that the row is visible
even if the row is hidden in the bottom of the scrollview and currently not appear

Comment: so your hidden rows are not actually Visibilty.Gone or Visiblity.Invisible, they are just not on the view of the actual device?

Comment: Yes  my hidden row's are only appear if I scroll down my table

Comment: Okay so they are not actually "hidden". You might need to get a little crafty with your XML layout but I would determine which rows are on the present screen by using the height of your layouts compared to the height of your device. It's hard to explain but its possible. I've done it before using an oversized linearlayout inside of a relativelayout but never with a scrollview. With linearlayouts you can manually set a scrollTo(X,Y) which is what I used in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag value set to true if the row is visible and the same to false if it is invisible. Then in your timer just check the boolean flag and if it is true update the content.